# JhiLanguageHelper doesn't find title

Tags: angular, jhipster

In the documentation is the following order for updateTitle():

```
 /**
 * Update the window title using params in the following
 * order:
 * 1. titleKey parameter
 * 2. $state.$current.data.pageTitle (current state page title)
 * 3. 'global.title'
 */
```

I've done some debugging and it tries to get the value based on the titleKey, which is "myApp" and as a result it sets the title as "translation-not-found[myApp]".

I don't have anywhere in i18n a value for "myApp". But I have the value in 'global.title'(#3)

What should I do to set the value for the title with point #3?

Comment: Which version of JHipster do you use? The comment you pasted seems to be related to an old version of JHipster when it was still using AngularJS 1.x.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou The project is using JHipster 4.14.3 and Angular 5.2.0

Comment: Then where did you get this doc from? $state.$current.data.pageTitle is about angular-ui router states not angular router routes, although the mechanism is relatively similar. So are you having a problem only with the global title or also with the pageTitle key of your routes?

Comment: The documentation is in the JhiLanguageHelper class, which was generated with JHIpster. I don't have different page titles, only one global title for the whole application.

Comment: Well, the comment in code was probably already obsolete at that time, it has been fixed since.  Normally you should have different titles for each entity routes and error routes.